# How should I connect my Nest thermostat to correct heating behavior?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

[image][image]I’m trying to fix our nest. For most of the winter, it blew heat if we turned on the ac. We didn’t have time to fix it so now I’m trying. I have photos of the thermostat and of the unit at the ac.

The first picture is the original wiring. The second is current. The third is wiring inside ac and 4th is where the wires originate from ac.

The orange and white wire seem to be my issue unless you see something else. We only have one unit that is both heat and ac. In Phoenix

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your heat source electricity, gas, or heat pump? The white wire being disconnected must be a problem: that's the one that's used to call for heating.. Also there's clearly an orange wire at the control board, but orange is not visible at the thermostat. Is it buried in the wall, or could there be a splice in the cable somewhere?

Comment: If this unit is a heat pump, the white wire should probably be in the `OB` terminal of the Nest thermostat. Look at how the terminal on the old thermostat says `W` above that terminal for conventional units and `O/B` below that same terminal for heat pumps.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your indoor unit (air handler) please?

Comment: There is no orange wire for the wiring that goes to the thermostat in that group of wires the only colors we have in that set of wires are the ones shown in the thermostat. I’ll try to post I’ll see what all we have it’s an electric York. I have no idea about pump it’s our unit for heating and cooling. So when I have orange connected to white I can run heat but the thermostat has to be set to ac. I tried hooking blue common to orange and bypass it connecting blue to ob on my thermostat but it said no power the nest has batteries so it confused me.

Comment: I also tried connecting white to white but the orange is hanging so obviously it won’t work because I’m missing something. I get it needs ob just trying to figure out if I need to add wiring to bring the orange wire into play.

Comment: I added a photo of where the wires connnect to the thermostat.

Comment: Go back to your original wiring.  Then check your reversing valve setting, somewhere in the Nest's settings menu.  Some heat pumps place an un-energized reversing valve in the heat position, while others put the valve in the cool position.  This was a problem I had with an ECOBEE smart thermostat and a Carrier heat pump system.

Comment: Thank you so what I did was kept 5 wire colors connected the orange from my unit to the thermostat white , put in in o/b. Then reset my nest and redid the wiring I just have skipped the part that asks if I’m using o or b wire once I put in that I was using o for the o/b my ac kicked on!!!!

Comment: @EdenOssinger make sure your heat kicks on too ;)